# Stacked records to columns

Tags: text-processing, osx, bsd

Have a file like this:

```
1
2
3
     # always a double newline
a
b
c     # each subgroup has the same number of rows

9
10

y
z
...
```

It's basically column1, followed by a double newline, then column two, double newline, and back to column1

Don't make assumptions about the nature of the values (they could be anything), or the number of "columns" (it could be 2 or 3, though known in advance)

Hoping for output like this:

```
1,a
2,b
3,c
9,y
10,z
...
```

What's the right tool for the job?

Comment: Neil, while what you posted is a good question, you really should add all essential information to your question.  Posing requirements for one thing in your question, but then revealing completely different requirements in comments under question - that's not acceptable. Please edit your post with appropriate examples of input and output that you expect. Until then , question voted to be closed as unclear.

Comment: Change whatever code produced this output to produce output that is better, or at least better suited for parsing.

Comment: @Kusalananda gimme a break. It's an external program

Comment: @Serg updated my question

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Well, I'm not telepathic.

Comment: Why don't you accept any of the answers bellow...? There are good answers down there. Are you expecting something different or something  specific to a dedicated program

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I don't accept answers for 72 hours, to allow time for others to chime in

Answer (score 3):

Another solution using `awk` and `bash`:

```
paste -d, <(awk -v RS='\n\n' 'NR%2' file) <(awk -v RS='\n\n' '!(NR%2)' file)
```

This only takes into account empty lines as separators, non-empty lines can be anything.

Comment: This is a nice one man.

Comment: A bit more explanation would be nice, and this has the minor weakness that it can’t be used on an arbitrary standard input (e.g., a pipe) without using a temporary file. But, aside from that, this is a clever answer.

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution with your sample input file (i copy / paste your input data to a local file named c2.txt). 
It has not been tested under all conditions for possible failures, but you can give a try to see if the result satisfies you.

```
$ paste -d"," <(grep -E '[0-9]' c2.txt) <(grep -E '[a-z]' c2.txt)
1,a
2,b
3,c
9,y
10,z
```

Actually i grep the same file twice . One for numbers one for strings and paste brings them together.

Comment: nice one! up for a harder challenge where the values could be anything, and you can only use the double newline as a guide (and the fact that each sub-section is the same length)?

Comment: All the values could be anything? Even the numeric ones? If you can think of an example (and add it to your question) could give you more accurate answer. Above snippet ignores double lines , just greps nums and then greps letters.

Answer (score 1):

How about using awk in paragraph mode; splitting each odd record into an indexed array and then looping through it using the indices of the following even record:

```
awk -vRS= -F'\n' '
   NR%2 {split($0,a); next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print a[i],$i}
' OFS=, file
1,a
2,b
3,c
9,y
10,z
```

Using a newline field separator makes it safe for more general input e.g. given `file2`

```
foo
bar
baz bar

a
b
c

9
10

hello world
z
```

then

```
awk -vRS= -F'\n' '
  NR%2 {split($0,a); next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print a[i],$i}
' OFS=, file2
foo,a
bar,b
baz bar,c
9,hello world
10,z
```

Comment: hm, looks good. don't quite get it all but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Python 2 script

Since OP requested that input values can be anything and only double new-line can be used as guide  in [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340691/stacked-records-to-columns/340700#comment602328_340692) , here's alternative version of script ( original can be found in the edit history of this answer), using steeldriver's input file for testing:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
columns = []
counter = 0

def print_columns(cols):
    half = len(cols)/2
    print("\n".join([ x+","+y for x,y in  zip(cols[0:half],cols[half:]) ]))

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fd:
    for line in fd:
        if line.strip() == '':
            counter+=1
            continue
        if counter >0 and counter%4 == 0: 
            print_columns(columns)
            columns = []
            counter = 0
        columns.append(line.strip())
print_columns(columns)
```

Test run:

```
$ cat input.txt                                                                                                          
foo
bar
baz bar


a
b
c


9
10


hello world
z

$ ./columnate_file.py input.txt                                                                                          
foo,a
bar,b
baz bar,c
9,hello world
10,z
```

Comment: I think this does not work with the data of steeldriver solution (as has been requested by OP)...

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou  OK, I'll edit my answer once i am at my laptop, but this into really should be  edited into original question. Otherwise, questions that say A but really want B need some close votes for being unclear

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I've updated my answer , added alternative script